# Получить количество секунд из даты: узнать разницу в секундах между доставкой и моментом запуска этого скрипта

Tags: python

Имеется дата из служебных полей письма получаемая с помощью `a = email.utils.parsedate_tz(email_message['Received'].splitlines()[-1].strip())` вида `2016-Aug-04 08:24:38`.

Требуется взять текущую дату `b = datetime.datetime.now()` посчитать кол-во секунд и в `a` и в `b` и вычесть из текущей даты (b) дату письма (a), чтоб узнать разницу в **секундах** между доставкой и моментом запуска этого скрипта. Пытаюсь делать с помощью `b.strftime("%s") - a.strftime("%s")` но ничего не получается. Подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Ошибка в том, что через  strftime форматируется дата и время, а через strptime делается разбор, внешне похожи но назначение разное.

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо привести к объекту datetime через strptime

```
from datetime import datetime

mytime = '2016-Aug-04 08:24:38'
time_delta = datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(str(mytime), '%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(time_delta.total_seconds())
```

Если импорт идет от import datetime, то код становится

```
import datetime

mytime = '2016-Aug-04 08:24:38'
time_delta = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.strptime(str(mytime), '%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(time_delta.total_seconds())
```

Одинаково работает как на 2.7 так и на 3 версии питона

Разница между просто разницей в секундах и общей разницей

```
>>> mytime = '2015-Aug-04 08:24:38'
>>> time_delta = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.strptime(str(mytime), '%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> time_delta.total_seconds()
31627007.536519
>>> time_delta.seconds
4607
```

python < 2.7

```
from datetime import timedelta
try:
    timedelta.total_seconds // new in 2.7
except AttributeError:
    def total_seconds(td):
        return float((td.microseconds +
                      (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6)) / 10**6
    d = _get_dict(timedelta)[0]
    d['total_seconds'] = total_seconds
    // works now in 2.4
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318348/how-can-i-extend-pythons-datetime-datetime-with-my-own-methods/14214646#14214646

@user216763

```
RTFM: timedelta.total_seconds() 
Return the total number of seconds contained in the duration. 
Equivalent to (td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10**6 computed with true division enabled
```

Comment: Скрипт ломается потому что у меня импортируется весь `import datetime` если импортировать `from datetime import datetime` тогда ломается всё остальное, например `timedelta` . Кстати, может есть способ много проще, с помощью той же `datetime.timedelta` например?

Comment: А тут точно всё правильно? У меня разница между datetime.now() `datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 4, 10, 23, 53, 943796)` и `2015-09-24 14:38:30` получается 19 часов O.O

Comment: Если ломается, от `from datetime import datetime` то в примере выше просто используйте `datetime.datetime.strptime` и ` datetime.datetime.now()`.

Comment: @Ilia w495 Nikitin ага, так и делал - не работает. Говорит, нет таких модулей...

Comment: в ответе добавил вариант когда импорт идет import datetime. Работает одинаково и на 2.7 и на 3.5

Comment: Ага, спасибо, я сделал так: `(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 24, 14, 38, 30)).seconds` однако что в Вашем случае, что в моём, между локальным временем (2016, 8, 4, 11, 28, 46, 139845) и 2015-ым годом разница в ~20 часов. Я не понимаю почему так происходит :(

Comment: пример был для разницы в секунды, сейчас заменил на общие секунды, отличие в функциях .seconds и .total_seconds() В ответе добавил пример вывода почему так.

Comment: Всё ясно, спасибо большое! Только всё равно придётся искать другой вариант, у меня python не поддерживает total_seconds, обновить его - не представляется возможным :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318348/how-can-i-extend-pythons-datetime-datetime-with-my-own-methods/14214646#14214646 - пока не проверено, но внешне должно работать def total_seconds(td):

Comment: Вот чего подсказали: `RTFM:
timedelta.total_seconds()
Return the total number of seconds contained in the duration. Equivalent to (td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10**6 computed with true division enabled.` Иногда очень полезно читать маны! Ещё раз огромное спасибо за потраченное на меня время!

Comment: добавил в ответ ваш комментарий, эквивалент, через микросекунды работает так же везде, универсальнее, но кода больше.

Comment: 1- Ответ неправильный, если между время в письме использует другую часовую зону чем на машине где код исполняется  (в интернете следует ожидать, что люди могут посылать письма и из других временных зон) 2- ответ неправильный если смещение времени поменялось (например, переход с летнего на зимнее время произошел) с момента посылки письма (пару раз в году бывает во многих зонах). Это по первому примеру (дальше не смотрел)

Comment: Хотелось бы посмотреть на правильный ответ с точки зрения отправки писем. Хотя для аналитики интереснее дата перехода по ссылке или загрузки картинки в письме.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получить "секунды с эпохи" для текущего времени, достаточно [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time) вызвать.

Чтобы получить секунды из строковой даты, указанной в заголовках письма, можно использовать [`email.utils.mktime_tz()`](https://docs.python.org/library/email.util.html#email.utils.mktime_tz) функцию. Чтобы получить искомую разницу в секундах:

```
from email.utils import mktime_tz, patsedate_tz

then = mktime_tz(parsedate_tz(email_time_str))
now = time.time()
difference_in_seconds = (now - then)
```

Этот код поддерживает разные часовые пояса  и работает даже во время перехода с зимнего на летнее время в текущей системной часовой зоне.

Если  нужны `datetime.datetime` объекты или нужна поддержка Python 2.6 или наоборот есть возможность использовать Python 3.3+, то см. [примеры кода как распознать время в письмах на разных версиях Питона (2.6-3.3+)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23117071/4279).

Чтобы избежать распространённых ошибок (таких как  в другом ответе на данный вопрос), связанных с временны́ми зонами, с разницей в реализациях времени на популярных платформах, посмотрите подробные ответы на связанные вопросы:

- [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279)
- [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8777753/4279)