# Как узнать через сколько секунд будет определенное время?

Tags: python, datetime

Я получаю текущую дату через

```
time.time()
```

Как узнать через сколько секунд будут ближайшие 18:00 времени?

Например, время 01:00 Ночи и надо чтобы скрипт сам определил, что 18:00 будет через 17ч (61200 сек)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получить количество секунд из даты: узнать разницу в секундах между доставкой и моментом запуска этого скрипта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/551754/178576)

Comment: ну и [тому подобные дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin не дубликаты, или по крайней мере не полностью дубликаты. Там считают разницу между заранее известными датами, а тут будущая дата изначально неизвестна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На первый взгляд может показаться, что решение тривиально и достаточно использовать [datetime.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) для установки нужного часа и посчитать разницу между двумя датами:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

current = datetime.now()  # Текущее время в местном часовом поясе
future = current.replace(hour=18, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

# Если мы хотим знать именно будущие 18 часов, то нужно проверить,
# что future указывает не в прошлое. Если сейчас вечер после 18 часов,
# значит будущие 18 часов находятся в следующих сутках — добавляем их
if future <= current:
    future += timedelta(days=1)

print((future - current).total_seconds())  # Результат может быть НЕВЕРНЫЙ!
```

Проблема в том, что это **не сработает** в трёх ситуациях:

- если в вашем часовом поясе между текущей и будущей датой есть переход на летнее/зимнее время — тогда будет добавляться/удаляться один лишний час;
- если будущая дата может не существовать в вашем часовом поясе — например, если вы вместо 18:00 захотите 02:30, то в России до 2011 года такое время **не существовало** один раз в год (в марте). Сейчас в России летнее время отменено, но есть много других стран, в которых летнее время всё ещё есть (например, та же соседняя Украина);
- если будущая дата существует два раза — при переходе с летнего на зимнее время стрелки часов сдвигаются на час назад.

Вот примеры дат, на которых будет некорректный результат (московский часовой пояс):

```py
current = datetime(2011, 3, 27, 0, 0, 0)  # Полночь 27 марта
print((future - current).total_seconds())
# 64800 — НЕВЕРНО, лишний час (был перевод стрелок на час вперёд)
```

```py
current = datetime(2014, 10, 26, 0, 0, 0)  # Полночь 26 октября
print((future - current).total_seconds())
# 64800 — НЕВЕРНО, не хватает одного часа (был перевод стрелок на час назад)
```

```py
current = datetime(2014, 10, 26, 0, 0, 0)  # Полночь 26 октября
future = current.replace(hour=1, minute=30, second=0, microsecond=0)
print((future - current).total_seconds())
# 5400 — НЕПОНЯТНО, верно или нет (26 октября 1:30 наступало дважды из-за перевода стрелок)
```

Решить все эти проблемы можно с помощью модуля [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/), который умеет корректно работать с часовыми поясами.

```py
import pytz
tz = pytz.timezone("Europe/Moscow")  # Московский часовой пояс
```

Для решения проблемы лишнего/недостающего часа достаточно прописать датам правильный часовой пояс, а дальше всё посчитается корректно:

```py
current = tz.localize(datetime(2014, 10, 26, 0, 0, 0), is_dst=None)  # 2014-10-26 00:00:00+04:00
future = current.replace(hour=18, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
if future <= current:
    future += timedelta(days=1)
# Перегенерируем смещение для правильного учёта летнего/зимнего времени
future = tz.localize(future.replace(tzinfo=None), is_dst=None)  # 2014-10-26 18:00:00+03:00
print((future - current).total_seconds())
# 68400 — ВЕРНО, добавился один час из-за перевода стрелок
```

Однако если нужная вам дата не существует или неоднозначна, `pytz` сообщит вам о проблеме:

```py
current = tz.localize(datetime(2014, 10, 26, 0, 0, 0), is_dst=None)
future = current.replace(hour=1, minute=30, second=0, microsecond=0)
future = tz.localize(future.replace(tzinfo=None), is_dst=None)
# pytz.exceptions.AmbiguousTimeError: 2014-10-26 01:30:00
```

```py
current = tz.localize(datetime(2011, 3, 27, 0, 0, 0), is_dst=None)
future = current.replace(hour=2, minute=30, second=0, microsecond=0)
future = tz.localize(future.replace(tzinfo=None), is_dst=None)
# pytz.exceptions.NonExistentTimeError: 2011-03-27 02:30:00
```

Здесь вы должны сделать выбор, как конкретно вам нужно решить проблему. Если дата неоднозначная, вы можете выбрать летнее (`is_dst=True`) или зимнее (`is_dst=False`) время:

```py
current = tz.localize(datetime(2014, 10, 26, 0, 0, 0), is_dst=None)
future = current.replace(hour=1, minute=30, second=0, microsecond=0)

# 2014-10-26 01:30:00+04:00 — летнее время
future = tz.localize(future.replace(tzinfo=None), is_dst=True)
print((future - current).total_seconds())
# 5400 — 1.5 часа до момента перед переводом стрелок

# 2014-10-26 01:30:00+03:00 — зимнее время
future = tz.localize(future.replace(tzinfo=None), is_dst=False)
print((future - current).total_seconds())
# 9000 — 2.5 часа до момента после перевода стрелок
```

Если же нужная дата не существует (например, `2011-03-27 02:30:00`) — не уверен, что можно придумать универсальное решение. Вижу следующие варианты:

- указать какое-нибудь смещение с помощью того же самого параметра `is_dst` — результат будет неправильный, но он будет хоть какой-то;
- найти ближайшую существующую дату — я как раз задавал на днях вопрос об этом: [Как узнать ближайшее существующее локальное время?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1471906);
- пропустить несуществующую дату и просто добавить ещё один день;
- ничего не делать и сообщить пользователю, что он хочет невозможного.

Comment: Любопытно, что в "простой" реализации на самом деле не надо проверять, ушло ли времмя "вперед", или "назад".

Comment: @AlexTitov подождите ещё два часа и убедитесь, что на самом деле надо (если мы хотим узнать именно будущие 18 часов)

Comment: @AlexTitov вы в своём ответе схитрили, вместо `.total_seconds()` использовав `.seconds`, но так не честно :)

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

current = datetime.now()
future = datetime(year=2022, month=12, day=5, hour=18, minute=0) # для примера
delta = future - current

print(delta.seconds)
```

Переменная `delta` в этом случае будет `<type 'datetime.timedelta'>`

Comment: Не `delta.total_seconds()`?

Comment: Проблема в том, что в вашем примере мы уже знаем дату (future), мне же надо чтобы скрипт сам определял через сколько будет 18:00 (не зная даты, он должен сам ее определить), в этом и кроется проблема тк у меня возникают трудности с определением, например сколько в месяце/году дней для генерации даты

Answer (score 0):

Вот так работает, вроде, причем секунды считает корректно, даже если уже 19 часов!

```
from datetime import datetime

current = datetime.now()
delta = current.replace(hour=18, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) - current
print(delta.seconds)
```

Интересно, что будет поздно вечером 31-го декабря, когда изредка добавляют/убирают одну секунду, но вряд ли это так важно...

Comment: Если например `current = datetime(2011, 3, 27, 0, 0, 0)`, то результат будет неверный (подробнее в моём ответе)

Comment: А насчёт добавления одной секунды - современные системы не учитывают это абсолютно никак, так что ничего особенного не произойдёт, но кто-то должен будет синхронизировать время в системе с реальным временем (обычно это происходит само, если в системе включена служба NTP)

Comment: Кстати, я что-то совсем пропустил новость о том, что [добавление/удаление одной секунды отменили](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-022-03783-5)